# Accessing viewModel properties

Tags: templates, binding, viewmodel, knockout.js

I have a template binding as follows

```html
<tbody id ="mytemplatetbody"
       data-bind="template: {name: 'myTemplate', foreach: Items}">
</tbody>
```

The rows in template have a status field whose value can be 1 or 2 or 3. There are three checkboxes on this screen and depending on what checkbox(es) user selects, the rows should be visible.

This is what I have done: Added three observable properties to viewModel and tied them to the three checkboxes. I can display those values as follows:

```html
<span data-bind="text: viewModel.checkBox1Selected()"></span>
```

Question: I am not able to put any if statements in my template for example like this...

```
{{if viewModel.checkBos1Selected() }}
```

...so what is the best way or anyway I can accomplish what I described above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to do this type of thing is to create a dependentObservable to represent your filtered rows.  Then, bind your template against this dependentObservable.  Whenever one of your observable filters changes, then the filtered rows will be re-evaluated.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BXeCb/

You can certainly do the filtering however works best for your app.  I used the checked binding against an observableArray to hold my filters, but you could easily go with your method of using three observable properties on your view model.

Comment: The filtering works based on checkbox selection flawlessly, I have another filtering I need to do additionally to the same data. When user logs into this app, the only rows that should be displayed are the ones that are created by him (we have createdby column in db), how do I do that?