# KnockOutJS show/hide rows based on if logged in user is the creator of that record

Tags: templates, filter, knockout.js

I have a situation where I need to filter data in data bound template using checkboxes. I got it to working now, thanks to RP Niemeyer for his response.

[Accessing viewModel properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339478/knockoutjs-accessing-viewmodel-properties)

Now the filtering works based on checkbox selection flawlessly, I have another filtering I need to do additionally to the same data. When user logs into this app, the only rows that should be displayed are the ones that are created by him (we have createdby column in db), how do I do that? The user id is available in viewModel and current logged in user id is store in session as userid.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly include additional filters in the filtering code like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Yrxfe/

I would make sure that you get the currently logged in user to be a part of your viewModel, then you can compare the createdby user with the currently logged in user in the dependentObservable that returns your filtered rows.

Comment: Dont know how to thank you not only for the best answer but how quick it was. It worked flawlessly, I hope there is some documentation with these details. Appreciate it.